# Save adapter array when new item added to Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I just started learn Android. I'm not sure if my question is correct or not. My purpose is when user press on button add item to listview. Each single item (row) have 3 inputs. Currently my code adds item (row) when press on button. But its creating new array and deleting all user inputs. I also almost don't know Java (have very very little OOP skill). Can you answer what am I doing wrong?

**Activity:**

```
    package com.example.gereltod.test7;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SellActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<Items> items = new ArrayList<Items>();
    ItemsAdapter adapter;
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sell);

        adapter = new ItemsAdapter(this, items);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_main);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void add_item(View view) {

        Log.i("clicked add item", "yes");

        items.add(new Items("", "", ""));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**Layout**

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView_main"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_add_item" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_add_item"
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_item"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="add_item" />
```

**Items Adapter**

```
package com.example.gereltod.test7;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ItemsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Items> {

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView qty;
        TextView price;
    }

    public ItemsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Items> items) {
        super(context, 0, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        Items items = getItem(position);
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag
        if (convertView == null) {
//            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edittxt_name);
            viewHolder.qty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edittxt_qty);
            viewHolder.price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edittxt_price);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.name.setText(items.name);
        viewHolder.qty.setText(items.qty);
        viewHolder.price.setText(items.price);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**List item**

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittxt_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@drawable/input_shape"
            android:hint="@string/hint_item_name"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittxt_qty"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/input_shape"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:hint="@string/hint_item_qty"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittxt_price"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:background="@drawable/input_shape"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:hint="@string/hint_item_price"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

**Edit: Since my English sucks, I can't exactly describe whats going on. So I added screenshot. See here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNQlQ.jpg**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating every time a new list and adding an item to the list and then setting the adapter of single list to listview.

Set the adapter on create of activity and then add items to adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged() method. Here is the code for activity:

```
public class SellActivity extends Activity {

   ArrayList<Items> items = new ArrayList<Items>();

   private ItemsAdapter adapter;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_sell);

       ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_main);

       adapter = new ItemsAdapter(this);
       listView.setAdapter(adapter);
   }

   public void add_item(View view) {

       Log.i("clicked add item", "yes");

       adapter.add(new Items("", "", ""));

       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
}
```

Comment: You have to do make a change in adapter also. Remove the list parameter from adapter :


List<Items> items = new ArrayList<>();

public ItemsAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, 0, items);
    }

Comment: Can you change adapter for me? I took that file from other tutorial. Can't change my self. When i remove 2nd parameter, there is whole log of errors appearing.

Comment: I have added the code in previous comment. please check.

Comment: Still resetting all previous entered texts.

Comment: Update your nee code in your question so that I can check what is wrong.

Comment: Updated to latest one.

Comment: Use :
adapter.add(new Items("", "", ""));

instead of :
items.add(new Items("", "", ""));

Comment: Still resetting all previous entered texts

Answer (score 0):

In your add_item method you should not create new adapter and new reference to listView. move these lines in your onCreate() method

```
ItemsAdapter adapter = new ItemsAdapter(this, items);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_main);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

add_item should only adding item and notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'adapter' on adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in add_item() function

Comment: ItemsAdapter should be a class level variable. Initialized in onCreate.

Comment: Yes look at the answer by Christopher... that is what i meant.

Comment: What is getting cleared... you are adding blank when add_item is called

Comment: Lets say I added first row. It adds 3 inputs. And lets say I entered text to them like "item1", "item2", "item3". Then when I add 2nd row, all previous input texts are resetting.

Comment: Dude, your edit texts are inside your row layout. They should be outside the list view.

Comment: I added explanation image at very bottom of main question. See that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quit sure but try this

```
package com.example.gereltod.test7;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SellActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<Items> items = new ArrayList<Items>();
    ItemsAdapter adapter;
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sell);

        adapter = new ItemsAdapter(this, items);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_main);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public void add_item(View view) {

        Log.i("clicked add item", "yes");

        items.add(new Items("", "", ""));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

i have a feeling this should work...

Comment: Same. When I press on add_item button, it's clearing all input values.

Comment: I also suspect ItemAdapter.java. I was following this tutorial and customized it bit for my case. https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Comment: First I downloaded code from github (above tutorial's). Then modified it. Tutorial was all about displaying custom list item. My case is, display custome items with **inputs**. Then my next goal is send this items array to database.

Comment: ok, now what do you mean "it's clearing all input values" are you talking about the EditText views?

Comment: When I press on add items button, it adds 3 EditText (inputs). When press again it adds another 3. But when it add, its clearing all previous texts in previous added inputs.

Comment: See main post again. I added explanation image at very bottom.

Comment: ooh now i get what you are looking for... the editText have the same id... i really don't know how to explain that but i guess you get the picture

Comment: i think what you should do is populate every row with a unique EditText id

Comment: You mean generate new id when create rows? How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You must change this method . first initialize your adapter into

```
onCreate() { 
   adapter = new ItemsAdapter(this, items); 
   listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_main);
   listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

ItemsAdapter adapter;
ListView listView;
public void add_item(View view) {
    Log.i("clicked add item", "yes");
    items.add(new Items("", "", ""));

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Still same. resetting previous input texts.

Comment: can you show me your modified version of your code? (edit your code)

Comment: but this is not what I adviced you

Comment: add this into add_item method listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: still same. resetting previous input texts.

Comment: do you have this project on github? if yes give me the link and i'll fix

Comment: Actually I don't have. But I can make zip file and upload somewhere (maybe dropbox)

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19063820/Test7.zip here is link. First page connects to running API (which you don't have). Please set main activity to SellActvitiy or use some other way to access it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't set the information taken from the input to the arraylist so, it doesn't have any information inside.